# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto' even after installing it

Tags: python, firebase, cryptography, jupyter

I am trying to run a Jupyter notebook cell that uses firebase module on MacOS Big Sur Python 3.8.2 but it keeps returning this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'
```

I ran a pip install Crypto but it said requirement already satisfied

```
Requirement already satisfied: Crypto in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Naked in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Crypto) (0.1.31)
Requirement already satisfied: shellescape in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Crypto) (3.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Naked->Crypto) (5.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Naked->Crypto) (2.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests->Naked->Crypto) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests->Naked->Crypto) (2020.12.5)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests->Naked->Crypto) (1.26.3)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<5,>=3.0.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests->Naked->Crypto) (4.0.0)
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

It still shows the same after I restarted the kernel and even reinstalled the firebase module.